# Activity no se inicia desde un servicio en Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, activity

En Kotlin, tengo un servicio que está esperando datos, la idea es que cuando reciba cierta información inicie una Activity asi este abierta o cerrada la Activity y muestre dichos datos, para eso tengo el servicio en primer plano, por lo que siempre está activo, el detalle es que al recibir un dato y querer iniciar una Activity desde el servicio no lo hace, solo cuando está abierta la Activity se reabre, pero si la cierro solo recibo en consola que recibí nuevos datos, pero la Activity no se abre, este es mi codigo actual en mi servicio:

```
println("1")
      val intent = Intent(this@MiServicio,MiActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("extra","data")
            }
        
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(intent)

println("2")
```

No me lanza ningun error, se ejecutan las println 1 y 2 pero no abren la Activity
Espero me pueda apoyar, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Es recomendable siempre revisar el LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si inicias una Activity desde un servicio es importante que tengas registrada la Activity en tu AndroidManifest.xml y que uses el contexto para usar el método `startActivity()`..

En el caso de tratar de abrir una activity desde un servicio, usa como contexto el mismo servicio:

```
        val intent = Intent(this@MiServicio,MiActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("extra","data")
        }
    
        intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        //Abre activity
        this@MiServicio.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Que genial!, solo me faltaba el this@ antes de MiServicio.StartActivity(). No pude dormir anoche por este inconveniente, mil gracias!!

Comment: Excelente @CarlosDanielZárateRamírez, saludos!

Comment: Ya la he marcado como solucionado pero me vuelve a hacer lo mismo, dejó de abrir las Activities, solo las abre cuando tengo la Activity abierta, las vuelve a abrir, pero si está cerrado solo ejecuta el startActivity pero no abre nada

Comment: @CarlosDanielZárateRamírez lo que comentas seguramente es por el uso de:  intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) elimina esta linea